# HTML full screen side without scrollbars

Tags: html, css

I tried to create a full screen website without scrollbars and have problems defining the margins for that. Given is a minimum example:

```css
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    background: green;
}

h1 {
    background: gray;
}
```

```html
    <body>
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    </body>
```

Why do I get the yellow background of the `html` element in the top of the side? Even more surprising to me is that the yellow part disappears, if I add text before the `h1` element.

```css
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    background: green;
}

h1 {
    background: gray;
}
```

```html
    <body>
        Add some text and the yellow part disappears.
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    </body>
```

Is there any idea to avoid the yellow part in the top without adding text before the heading element?

Comment: Try Googling "Collapsing Margins".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `body` element is a non-floating block-element, just as the contained `h1` element. Therefore the size/position of the `body`element adapts to its child-element `h1`, which has a margin (margin-top) defined as default.

There are multiple solutions for your problem, one is to make the body-element float. The advantage of this is (compared to removing the margin on the h1) is, that it will work the same way, even if a different element with a margin is inserted.

```css
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    background: green;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

h1 {
    background: gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    </body>
```

```css
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    background: green;
    float: left; 
    width: 100%;
}

h1 {
    background: gray;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is why often something like [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) is added to a project to avoid these things with different browsers etc. `height: 100vh;` would work. To get ride of scroll bars you can also use `overflow-y: hidden;` or `overflow-x: hidden;` depending on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `margin-top:0;` on your `h1`. [Example here](http://jsbin.com/kaqabibexi/edit?html,css,output)

I recommend using a CSS reset to avoid problems like this. [Eric Meyer's](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) is very well-known and simple.

Answer (score 0):

When starting a new project or as a general rule, always try to reset a lot of the predefined css values that browsers "add". There's some "css reset" stylesheets already created, which you can find with a google search, but for a simple solution you can always start with:

```
* { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

Then you can always add additional rules that will affect all elements in your document like "font-family: sans-serif" etc. 
That way you're sure that you have a solid starting point without having too many different looks across browsers.

Later on you can then add the rules more explicitly to the elements that need styling

Answer (score 0):

this is how I would do a full screen website and it is very simple and clean:

```
<body>

<h1>Main heading</h1>

</body>
```

The CSS code:

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

So, if you give to your body a height of 100vh (viewport height) it will stay 100% of the window, no matter the size of it.Like this you won't have a problem with scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.img-responsive { background-size: 100%; }
OR

.img-responsive { background-size: cover; }
```

**Instead of img tag, use background-image for fullscreen image.**

```
<header>
  <div class="menu_area">...</div>
</header>


html, body, header {
    height: 100%;
}
header {
    background-image: url('images/image1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}
```